# How can I easily toggle the cursor size back and forth between normal and largest?

Tags: mouse, accessibility

I'm using Mac OS 10.8.3.  I have a huge display and bad eyes, so I like to have the mouse cursor be the largest possible size. (under *System Preferences*: *Accessibility*: *Display*: **Cursor size**.

However, I also do a fair amount of video editing, for which I use Final Cut Pro X.  Unfortunately, the UI designers who made the Final Cut Pro X interface didn't properly take into account larger cursor sizes, so when I click a button in the program's interface with the "tip" of a large cursor, it won't register.  To remedy this, when I'm using Final Cut Pro X, I change the cursor size back to normal.

However, doing this is fairly time consuming, as I have to do it a few times every day.  Is there a way to somehow do this automatically?

Comment: Did you try different type of cursor?

Comment: @Buscar웃 No, I'm using the default OS X cursor.

Comment: This also is a problem with the text insert cursor as the active point is not at the tip so you constantly have to make a small adjustment with the large cursor, and some apps (I think non Cocoa ones) don't show the cross piece

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is too *excessive* but you could create an **AppleScript** which would toggle the size of the cursor. To do so just:

1. Go to **System Preferences / Universal Access** and *check* **Enable access for assistive devices**, this will let you use AppleScript to query and control the user interface of most Applications.
2. Go to **/Applications / Utilities / AppleScript Editor** and paste this code and save it as Application:

   ```
   tell application "System Preferences"

       set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"

       tell application "System Events"

           repeat until slider "Cursor size:" of window "Accessibility" of process "System Preferences" exists
           end repeat

           set theSlider to slider "Cursor size:" of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"

           set stash to value of theSlider
           if value of theSlider is 1.0 then
               set value of theSlider to 2.2
           else
               set value of theSlider to 1.0
           end if
           stash

       end tell
   end tell
   ```

Comment: I had no idea that you could do this in AppleScript.  Actually, what I really wanted to do was toggle back and forth between cursor sizes, so I updated your answer to show how to do that.

Comment: @Mark You can use the script to toggle.  It's not global, but if you bind it to a hotkey using Alfred or a similar app, you can get a pretty close approximation.

Comment: I've tried the above script but it produces this error: System Events got an error: Can’t get group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences". Invalid index. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @PatrickKenny my preference is to create a Service using Automator and then set keyboard shortcut in the 'System Preferences' to use this service. I prefer to avoid third party software, such as Alfred.

Comment: @user56968 did you ever got it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated version of Thecafremo's AppleScript from 2013 that works with Monterey 12.6

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate

tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    
    --wait for Accessibility Pane to open - Can go to 0.5 if you are impatient
    delay 1
    
    tell application "System Events"
        
        --Open Vision > Display menu
        select row 5 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences" of application "System Events"
        
        --Open Pointer Section menu
        click radio button "Pointer" of tab group 1 of group 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences" of application "System Events"
        
        
        --Change Pointer Size slider
        set theSlider to slider "Pointer size:" of tab group 1 of group 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"
        
        set stash to value of theSlider
        if value of theSlider is 1.0 then
            set value of theSlider to 4.0 --4.0 is max
        else
            set value of theSlider to 1.0 --1.0 is default
        end if
        
    end tell
end tell
--Uncomment the below to quit sys prefs
--tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

Comment: Is there a way to run this from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an update of my previous script rewritten for System Settings in MacOS Ventura v14.0

If this fails to work first time try increasing the delay values.

```
tell application "System Settings" to activate

--Open System Settings > Accessibility > Display section
do shell script "open x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.universalaccess?Seeing_Display"

--Wait for correct pane to load
delay 2

tell application "System Events"
    
    --Get current state of slider --updated for sonoma
    set currentState to (get value of slider "Pointer size" of group 3 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of list 2 of splitter group 1 of list 1 of window "Display" of application process "System Settings" of application "System Events")
    
    --Determine key code to send
    if currentState is not greater than 1.0 then
        set keyCode to "116" as integer -- PageUp (increase size)
    else
        set keyCode to "121" as integer -- PageDown (decrease size)
    end if
    
    
    --set focus to slider
    tell slider "Pointer size" of group 3 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of list 2 of splitter group 1 of list 1 of window "Display" of application process "System Settings" of application "System Events" to set focused of it to true
    
    delay 0.2
    
    --Send keycode to set size to max or min
    key code keyCode
    
end tell
delay 2.5
tell application "System Settings" to quit
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore. I'm getting the error: `System Events got an error: Can’t get list 1 of window "Display" of application process "System Settings".`

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I know of is to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and then click on **Preferences** to adjust.

A note about large cursor: Changing the cursor size has no impact on the click focus, the point of the cursor remains the same. Which means that you have only magnified your cursor, so the active click point has moved and it is no longer exactly at arrow tip.

In English....try clicking not with the tip of large cursor but more in to it.

You might like the pointer from [Mouseposé](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mousepose/id405904955?mt=12). It cost $5 and you will not have to switch back and forth.

Comment: If mousepoint just highlights the cursor, then it is similar to the free OmniDazzle but it does make finding the cursor easier but it still has the issue that the OP asks in some cases you need the smaller cursor

Comment: The sole reason for large cursor is to find/see it. The suggestion for Mousepose is to use alternative method rather than switching and it does not make the original cursor larger. Thanks for "free" Omnidazzle hint.

Comment: Even with Omnidazzle or Mouseposé you need the large cursor, this is from my own usage. The program allows you to see where it is on the screen but is distracting, to do work you need just the cursor and it needs to be big to be seen. This could be different for other users