# Is there a Quick switch for trackpad mouse pointer MBA 10.9.1

Tags: trackpad

Here is the situation.

When working inside the current mouse pointer is fine on my MBA 10.9.1.

However, when I decide to use my MBA outside in the Sun, I can't see my mouse pointer very well.

Is there a way to use a shortcut or script to switch mouse pointer to something highly visible when working in the Sun light.

Yes, I know Preferences + accessibility + Size change, just wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut or something like it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I easily toggle the cursor size back and forth between normal and largest?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88267/how-can-i-easily-toggle-the-cursor-size-back-and-forth-between-normal-and-larges)

Comment: Thank you, that is nice but not a keyboard shortcut, my problem is once outside in the sun i can not find my cursor to click on anything, I know it is embarrassing. Maybe I use a combo of that script and run it with a keyboard shortcut :). Make that in a answer and I will gift you.

Comment: On a side note, you could use something like [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) to automate this, by having a context based on the ambient brightness level (Light Sensor). You'd probably need to use an AppleScript to do the actual config change (e.g. from answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign the script to a keyboard shortcut, you can assign it an [Automator Service](http://www.macosxautomation.com/lion/automatorservices.html).

Open Automator.app and choose Service, and set the "Recieves `text`" at the top to `no input`.

Drag in the "Run AppleScript" action from the Library. You can find it by searching for applescript on the left side of the window.

Replace what the action already contains with the script below.

Save, then go to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services` to add the shortcut keys you want (click add shortcut on the right).

[image: Screenshot of Services Keyboard Shortcuts prefpane]

This is the script:

```
property largeCursorSize : 2.0 --1x to 4x size
tell application "System Preferences" to reveal anchor "Seeing_Display" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
tell application "System Events"
    set theSlider to slider "Cursor Size:" of group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
    if value of theSlider is 1.0 then
        set value of theSlider to largeCursorSize
    else
        set value of theSlider to 1.0
    end if
end tell
```